# how to execute bash script inside vps remotely

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, vps

I have a task to give to a second developer the ability to restart gunicorn service, without giving him access to whole virtual machine, he is able to upload his projects files via ftp in his projects directory, but he can't restart gunicorn himself.

my "script.sh" is:

`sudo service gunicorn restart`

[image: bashscript]

i can execute script.sh myself in terminal with this command, it works fine:
`./script.sh`

How can i execute this script remotely?  Maybe via url?
Or maybe if there any other better ways to complete this task, please share

Thank you!

Comment: There are _so many_ ways. You can write a service that when a file is uploaded to  a specific directory it will detect that and do what you want. You can setup a http REST api with some service. You can write a custom protocol service. You can give ssh access to the develop with a special sudo access to only trigger this specific action. You can setup a service that when you receive a special email, that you will receive from the developer, it will read the email and execute the action. It's too broad - how do you _want_ to solve the problem?

Comment: All of these ways seems interesting!
if you can tell more specific, maybe with some links to guides\articles\videos, i would be very happy! I like two of your ideas most, one is writing a service that detect uploaded files in specific directory. And second is to give to the developer access with which he could trigger only specific commands. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like two of your ideas most, one is writing a service that detect uploaded files in specific directory

Basically a script:

```
inotifywait /the/dir -m -e CREATE,CLOSE | while read -f action file; do 
      rm "$file"
      systemctl restart that_thing
done
```

with maybe some filtering on specific file names and/or password checking like the content of the filename has to be some password.

If you do not use Linux, instead of inotifywait you could just poll for the file existence, each second or so.

See `man inotifywait`, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 + https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide . I doubt your server uses rc-scripts , it's 2021, consider moving to systemd. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/introduction-to-systemctl/ + https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/ .

> And second is to give to the developer access with which he could trigger only specific commands

Setup ssh server, give the developer an user account, install `sudo` and then create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/other_developer` with the content:

```
otherdeveoperuseraccount ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart that_service
```

Then the other developer will be able to run that specific command.

See `man sudo` and `man sudoers` and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279125/allow-user-to-run-a-command-with-arguments-which-contains-spaces . Overall, as to how to setup ssh server and add user accounts, interest in some basic introduction to Linux computer administartion - surely there are endless online.

Comment: Will the user have access to run standard shell commands like `ls` over ssh with the sudoers entry?

Comment: `Will the user have access to run standard shell commands like ls over ssh with the sudoers entry?` yes. That's sounds fine - he's a developer, not a user. You can seutp a chroot to restrict the access to just dbus and systemctl.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer! I appreciate it! Second variant worked fine i only changed to this: developername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service gunicorn restart. i'll definitely try ftp variant also, it looks harder, but safer. Can't upwote your answer, not enough reputation

Comment: Still, if you are looking for a real setup, it would be way better to setup a Ci/CD pipeline (for example as part of GitLab) to do all the restarting automatically as part of each commit CD. Or for example do deployments with Docker or Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

#### One way:

1. Create a user with min-privileges. (unfortunately some shell privilege is req).
2. Override `The ONLY command` which forcibly runs on ssh for this user.

```sh
# 1. Create a user with shell = /bin/sh & no home-dir
sudo adduser limiteduser --shell=/bin/sh --no-create-home

# 2. Restrict further in sshd_config
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

## > Add the following at the end
Match user limiteduser
  ForceCommand /path/to/restart-script
  # ForceCommand ls    # Tried this for testing.
```

P.S: Some side effects include `limiteduser` having access to tunnel ports. Since the user already has FTP access; I am assuming that security requirements aren't super tight.

---

#### Another way - since FTP access is present.

- When the user is done with FTP upload, ask him to create a file at a location: `/path/to/ftp/folder/request-restart.txt`
- `[Per-minute]` Write a cron job which checks for this file & runs the restart script & deletes the file.

  - The inotify script in @kamilkuk 's answer is a finer real time version of this. with cron the max resolution is 1 minute.
- This can be extended to provide more `request-some-other-command` for the user.

```sh
# cron-watch-n-restart-script.sh
FILE="/path/to/ftp/folder/request-restart.txt"
if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    /path/to/restart-script.sh
    rm $FILE
fi

# Cron job entry (crontab -e): every minute
* * * * * /path/to/cron-watch-n-restart-script.sh
```

Comment: this is actually working very handy i only changed cron task. 
added it here "nano /etc/crontab" and this is the job "* *     * * *   root  /bin/bash /home/admin/agent/restart.sh" , thank you!